# How to write an bash alias to list all name-matching env-vars

Tags: bash, grep, alias

Hello friendly guys. On Linux with Bash, I often need to list environment variables(env-var) whose names start with some predefined word. For example, to list all env-vars with name pattern gmXXX, I will do

```
[chj @linux-ic37 ~]$ export|grep '^declare -x gm'
declare -x gmu_DO_SHOW_COMPILE_CMD="1"
declare -x gmu_DO_SHOW_LINK_CMD="1"
```

But writing that long command everytime is boring. So, can I write an alias to simplify it? I tried but no luck.

```
[chj @linux-ic37 ~]$ alias fvgm="export|grep \'^declare -x gm\'"

[chj @linux-ic37 ~]$ fvgm
grep: gm': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me out?

To make it further, can I go as far as having 'gm' parameterized, like

```
fv gm
```

to list all env-var starting with 'gm' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single-quote in your alias. Change it to:

```
alias fvgm="export|grep '^declare -x gm'"
```

You need to write a function to make it generic. For example:

```
fv(){
    export | grep "^declare -x $1"
}
```

You can then call:

```
fv gm
```

Answer (score 2):

How about: `fv() { env | grep "^$1"; }`

```
$ fv HO
HOSTNAME=...
HOSTTYPE=...
HOME=...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `compgen -v STR`

This will generate a list of all the variable names starting with STR
This should be a better option than piping `export` because it does not involve another process

So the same fv function can be written as  [edited to add values]

```
fv()
{
   for EV in $(compgen -v ${1}); do 
     eval echo "$EV=\$$EV"
   done
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it list only the variable names, not there values.

Comment: @Jimm  okay I modified to include the value.  The text of the question did not as for variables and their values, so downvoting on that basis is not cool